# How do I specify the path to any class in the makefile of a project?

Tags: java, makefile

I have a java project, with different directorys containing different classes. And I'm trying to create a makefile in the upper directory that links all the the classes and compiles de project.
So to reach class a, it should follow the path ./src/project/packageA/a.java, and to reach b, ./src/project/packageB/b.java.  I have the following makefile:

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
JVM = javac

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
    $(JC)$(JFLAGS)$*.java

CLASSPATH = .:./src/project

CLASSES = \
          a.java \
          b.java \
          ...

MAIN = Main

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

run: $(MAIN).class
    $(JVM)$(MAIN)

clean:
    $(RM)*.class
```

Where CLASSES is a macro containing all the classes in the project. I've tried redefining the variable PATH for every directory, assigning vpath and directly specifying the path in every's class name. But none seems to work, I always receive the error message "there is no rule for building the object a.class, needed for 'classes'." This is my first time using makefile and I don't know how to proceed.

Thank you everyone.

Comment: Assign CLASSPATH with the path that contains the parent folder of your top level package.

Comment: I have done it. I believe I should give the option -cp now before the name of the class, but then make identifies -cp as an object to build. Would it be easier (yet longer) to work without the macro CLASSES?

Comment: Can't help you with make but there are other tools closer to java that could be of use to know about like, ant, maven and gradle with good support in IDEs

Comment: The path that contains your top level package, **not** individual class files.

Comment: I know this is not the best method at all, but unfortunately this is what's demanded by my professor.

Comment: I have editted the question with the assigning of CLASSPATH. I understand this is the declaration you're refearing to. Is the syntax wrong?

Comment: Yes. You are creating a make variable. You need to set an environment variable, **or** use the `-cp` option to `javac`. As has already been noted, make was not designed for Java.

Answer (score 0):

Few minor fixes to move the project forward.

- Fix the rule for compile - need spaces around JFLAGS
- Use the input file for the build rule - so that it will include the full path name
- Add vpath to tell the compiler where source files can be

```
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $^

CLASSPATH = .:./src/project

vpath %.java src/project
```

It's not clear from the question where you want to place the object. Consider adding -d to specify target folder, and setting adding `cp -d ...` to specify the location for the run target. You will need to fix the run time to add spaces.